# How do we control dynamic ordering by a Field in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

I don't know if the question is correct with what I want, but:

I have a set of questions in a table that will be asked to clients in an specific order, and sometimes we need to insert new questions and also we need to move questions down or up.

I made a field called position, and some buttons to increase and decrease it's position so I can use a `SELECT ... ORDER BY` but it is not very good because sometimes two or more questions get the same position number and the MySQL selects their order.

So what is the proper way to get this working perfectly?

*Note: I can't use index to do that. It is obvious to some people, but to others, not...*

Comment: `ORDER BY order_field, some_other_field`? you don't have to sort by just ONE field...

Comment: Can't you build a graph of question ID's in memory and then retrieve them from the DB when needed? "sometimes we need to insert new questions and also we need to move questions down or up" suggests flow logic that would lend itself to a graph structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you right you need a way to properly manage sequence of values in `position` column when you insert new questions, change the position of an existing one or delete questions.

Let's say you have following DDL of your questions table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
    `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `question` VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL,
    `position` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and intitial data set like this

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | question   | position |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | Question 1 |        1 |
|  2 | Question 2 |        2 |
|  3 | Question 3 |        3 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

**To get ordered list of questions** you do obvious

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM questions 
 ORDER BY position;
```

**To insert a new question to the end of the question list** you do

```sql
INSERT INTO questions (question, position) 
SELECT 'New Question', COALESCE(MAX(position), 0) + 1
  FROM questions;
```

Result will be:

```
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | question     | position |
+----+--------------+----------+
|  1 | Question 1   |        1 |
|  2 | Question 2   |        2 |
|  3 | Question 3   |        3 |
|  4 | New Question |        4 |
+----+--------------+----------+
```

**To insert a new question to a specific position** (let's say to position 3) in list you do it with two queries:

```sql
UPDATE questions
   SET position = position + 1
 WHERE position >= 3;

INSERT INTO questions (question, position) 
VALUES ('Another Question', 3);
```

Now you have

```
+----+------------------+----------+
| id | question         | position |
+----+------------------+----------+
|  1 | Question 1       |        1 |
|  2 | Question 2       |        2 |
|  5 | Another Question |        3 |
|  3 | Question 3       |        4 |
|  4 | New Question     |        5 |
+----+------------------+----------+
```

**To swap positions of two questions** (e.g. questions with ids 2 and 5) you do

```sql
UPDATE questions AS q1 INNER JOIN 
       questions AS q2 ON q1.id = 2 AND q2.id = 5
   SET q1.position = q2.position,
       q2.position = q1.position
```

Let's see what we've got

```
+----+------------------+----------+
| id | question         | position |
+----+------------------+----------+
|  1 | Question 1       |        1 |
|  5 | Another Question |        2 |
|  2 | Question 2       |        3 |
|  3 | Question 3       |        4 |
|  4 | New Question     |        5 |
+----+------------------+----------+
```

That's exactly what you do when user clicks on your up and down buttons, supplying correct question ids.

Now if you want to keep your positions sequence without gaps when you delete question you can do that.

**To delete from end of the list** you use simple delete

```sql
DELETE FROM questions WHERE id=4;
```

Results

```
+----+------------------+----------+
| id | question         | position |
+----+------------------+----------+
|  1 | Question 1       |        1 |
|  5 | Another Question |        2 |
|  2 | Question 2       |        3 |
|  3 | Question 3       |        4 |
+----+------------------+----------+
```

**Deleting a question in the middle (or beginning) of the list** requires more work. Let's say we want to delete the question with id=5

```sql
-- Get the current position of question with id=5
SELECT position FROM questions WHERE id=5;
-- Position is 2
-- Now delete the question
DELETE FROM questions WHERE id=5;
-- And update position values
UPDATE questions
   SET position = position - 1
 WHERE position > 2;
```

And finally we have

```
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | question     | position |
+----+--------------+----------+
|  1 | Question 1   |        1 |
|  2 | Question 2   |        2 |
|  3 | Question 3   |        3 |
+----+--------------+----------+
```

**UPDATE**: To make our life easier we can wrap it all in stored procedures

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE add_question (q VARCHAR(256), p INT)
BEGIN

IF p IS NULL OR p = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO questions (question, position) 
    SELECT q, COALESCE(MAX(position), 0) + 1
      FROM questions;
ELSE
    UPDATE questions
       SET position = position + 1
     WHERE position >= p;

    INSERT INTO questions (question, position) 
    VALUES (q, p);
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE swap_questions (q1 INT, q2 INT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE questions AS qs1 INNER JOIN 
           questions AS qs2 ON qs1.id = q1 AND qs2.id = q2
       SET qs1.position = qs2.position,
           qs2.position = qs1.position;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_question (q INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT position INTO @cur_pos FROM questions WHERE id=q;
    SELECT MAX(position) INTO @max FROM questions;

    DELETE FROM questions WHERE id=q;

IF @cur_pos <> @max THEN 
    UPDATE questions
       SET position = position - 1
     WHERE position > @cur_pos;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and use them like this:

```sql
-- Add a question to the end of the list
CALL add_question('How are you today?', 0);
CALL add_question('How are you today?', NULL);

-- Add a question at a specific position
CALL add_question('How do you do today?', 3);

-- Swap questions' positions
CALL swap_questions(1, 7);

-- Delete a question
CALL delete_question(2);
```

Comment: You are simple the best, as Tina Turner would say! Thank you!